# I am trying to pass the metric of a gRPC protocol to kubernetes istio. I am using java spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, grpc, istio

I have an external request to the aggregator, from which there is a request to the gRPC server.
I only get metrics from ingress-gateway to aggregator. and from the aggregator to the grpc service. It turns out that I do not build a complete query dependency tree, but only two parts of it. How can I get the complete dependency tree?

[image]

second metrics

[image]

my dependencies

```
     <dependency>
            <groupId>net.devh</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

my code

```
@Service
public class GrpcService {

    @GrpcClient("square")
    private SquareRpcGrpc.SquareRpcBlockingStub blockingStub;

    @GrpcClient("square")
    private SquareRpcGrpc.SquareRpcStub asyncStub;

    public Object getSquareResponseUnary(int number){
        return IntStream.rangeClosed(1, number)
                .mapToObj(i -> Input.newBuilder().setNumber(i).build())
                .map(this.blockingStub::findSquareUnary)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Output::getNumber,
                        Output::getResult
                ));
    }

    public Object getSquareResponseStream(int number){
        CompletableFuture<Map<Integer, Integer>> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        OutputStreamingResponse outputStreamingResponse = new OutputStreamingResponse(
                new HashMap<>(),
                completableFuture
        );
        StreamObserver<Input> squareBiStream = this.asyncStub.findSquareBiStream(outputStreamingResponse);
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, number)
                .mapToObj(i -> Input.newBuilder().setNumber(i).build())
                .forEach(squareBiStream::onNext);
        squareBiStream.onCompleted();
        return completableFuture;
    }
}
```

proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";

package vinsmath;

option java_package = "com.vinsguru.model";
option java_multiple_files = true;

message Input {
  int32 number = 1;
}

message Output {
  int32 number = 1;
  int32 result = 2;
}

service SquareRpc {
  rpc findSquareUnary(Input) returns (Output) {};
  rpc findSquareBiStream(stream Input) returns (stream Output) {};

}
```

deployment and svc grpc

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: grpc-service
  labels:
    app: grpc
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: grpc
  ports:
  - name: grpc
    protocol: TCP
    port: 50101
    targetPort: 50101
---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: grpc
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: grpc 
      version: v1
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: grpc
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: grpc
          image: 13523661/grpc-square-service:6.9
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
          - containerPort: 50101
          env:
            - name: JAEGER_ENDPOINT
              value: http://jaeger-collector.istio-system.svc:14268/api/traces
            - name: JAEGER_PROPAGATION
              value: b3
---
```

Deployment aggregator

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: agr
  labels:
    app: agr
    service: agr
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    name: http
  selector: 
    app: agr
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: agr-v1
  labels:
    app: agr
    version: v1
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: agr
      version: v1
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: agr
        version: v1
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: agr
          image: 13523661/aggregator-service:6.9
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: GRPC_CLIENT_SQUARE_ADDRESS
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: secret-3
                  key: grpc.client.square.address
            - name: REST_SQUARE_SERVICE_ENDPOINT
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: secret-3
                  key: rest.square.service.endpoint
            - name: JAEGER_ENDPOINT
              value: http://jaeger-collector.istio-system.svc:14250/api/traces
            - name: JAEGER_PROPAGATION
              value: b3
```

Maybe you have an example of how to get the full tracing span

Comment: Maybe you need a full version of my application, I'll leave a link to the github.
https://github.com/nikita111100/gRPC-vs-REST

Answer (score 0):

it works for me

@Configuration
public class TracingConfig {

```
@GrpcGlobalClientInterceptor
TracingClientInterceptor tracingInterceptor(Tracer tracer) {
    return TracingClientInterceptor
            .newBuilder()
            .withTracer(tracer)
            .build();
}
```

}

link  `https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-grpc`